# Как в google map подключить голосовой помощник?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Подскажите, куда копать? Пишу приложение под андроид используя google maps, google directions для построения маршрута. Необходимо каким то образом интегрировать голосовой помощник. Какие есть решения для этого? Еще нужно выводить дорожные подсказки.

Comment: Можно использовать стандартный [TTS](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech).

Comment: Да, понимаю! Но как мне сообщать, что поворот или прямая дорога?

Comment: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.19/dev_guide/topics/map-voice-instructions.html

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!!!

Comment: А есть еще варианты какие то кроме этого SDK? Возникли проблемы с их SDK

Comment: Какие проблемы? Голос платный?

Comment: По сути, вам не нужно никакое SDK, за голосовые подсказки отвечает TTS. За пошаговые инструкции - API Навигации.  Вам просто нужно взять пошаговые инструкции направить на TTS.

Comment: TTS под android много движков. По русски и мове хорошо шпрехает [RHVoice](https://rhvoice.org/).

Comment: У меня проблема не с голосом)) Как поставить TTS и заставить ему говорить слова, это понятно! Я не понимаю как мне заставить сообщать о повороте, пробках, и других приключениях на дороге.

Comment: А юзать HERE я так понимаю это не совсем бесплатно. За построение маршрутов тоже буду платить

Comment: Вы можете попробовать [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/navigation/) за это не надо платить.

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/directions/ вот еще нашел демку

Comment: Попробую, спасибо )))

Comment: Спасибо еще раз огромное тебе за помощь! Все таки установил HERE с голосом, очень доволен этой картой. Но не понимаю почему не могу установить title на маркеры.